# how to iterate through cursor in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have three columns in mongoDB. I want to retrieve data from the DB using node.js. I used the below code.

```
var myCursor = Users.find({USER_MOBILE_NUMBER : Auth.USER_MOBILE_NUMBER} , function(err , success){
        console.log('Response success '+success);
        console.log('Response error '+err);
    });

    myCursor.forEach(function(race) {
    console.log(race);    
    });
```

But when I run the code it returns null in the log for 'race'. I am new to node.js and I also searched a lot to find a solution, but I failed. Please help me where I went wrong in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an asynchronous function, you need to do your logic from within the callback as the find method doesn't actually return anything.

```
Users.find({USER_MOBILE_NUMBER : Auth.USER_MOBILE_NUMBER} , function(err , myCursor){
    myCursor.forEach(function(race) {
        console.log(race);    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It works fine. I would like to know more about the asynchronous functions and node.js. So pls give me some website references with examples.